# Set route name for POST, GET PUT, PATCH, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using `Devise` and change its default routes like this:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '',skip: [:sessions]

as :user do
    get '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#new', as: :password
    post '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#create'
    put '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#update'
    get '/password/edit' => 'users/passwords#edit'
end
```

The generated URL (form action attribute) for `new.html.erb` (view for sending email with new password instructions) is `/forgotten.user`, which is not correct. The correct URL is `/forgotten` and it is used with different HTTP verbs GET/POST/PUT.
 In request new password form (new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, 
             url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post})
```

Without my custom routes with `rake routes`, I see for these routes:

> user_password | PATCH  |  /password(.:format)       | users/passwords#update
>
> PUT | /password(.:format)  |             users/passwords#update
>
> POST |     /password(.:format) | users/passwords#create

How to make this route custom and used for different HTTP verbs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `as :user do`

```
get '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#new', as: :password
post '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#create'
put '/forgotten' => 'users/passwords#update'
get '/password/edit' => 'users/passwords#edit'
```

If you need to url be like `/user/forgotten` use `scope 'user' do`

Comment: `Could not find devise mapping for path "/forgotten". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]`